# Database Design - Items and Regions

Tags: hierarchical-data, regions, database-design

I have design problem of database structure.
The goal is to have database for offers that our clients offer per some geographical region. 
Each offer can be offered in many regions.

The regions are in hierarhy - example:

```
subregion_1
  subregion_11
    region_111
    region_112
  subregion_12
    region_121
    region_122
subregion_2
  subregion_21
    region_221
```

Now I want to store in database the offer_1 and regions for that offer. I will give You 3 examples what I have to ahieve:

- when my offer_1 is stored in region_111 then I would like to display this offer when user are browsing the subregion_1, subregion_11 and region_111
- If offer_1 is stored in regions subregion_11 and region_121 then the offer should be displayed when user are browsing the subregion_1, subregion_11 and all branch of subregion_11, subregion_12 and region_121
- when my offer_1 is stored in subregion_1 then the offer is displayed on subregion_1 page and all branch under subregion_1.

Also I have to provide a way to calculate the number of diffrent offers in each regions dynamicaly and very fast.
Does somebody have some advice how to aproach this design?

Here is what I have so Far.

```
Regions
------------------------------------------------------------
| id     | level1 | level2 | level3 | name         | level |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 02     | 02     | null   | null   | subregion_1  | 1     |
| 0201   | 02     | 01     | null   | subregion_11 | 2     |
| 020103 | 02     | 01     | 03     | region_111   | 3     |
------------------------------------------------------------

Offers to regions
------------------------
| offer_id | region_id |
------------------------
| 1        | 020103    |
| 1        | 0202      |
------------------------
```

I created id for regions from concatenating level1, level2 and level3. In the table Offers_to_regions I store the offer and the region. Here I have region on level 3 (020103) and region on level 2 (0202) for offer 1.
With this design I have problems how to query the numbers of difrent offers per region, and how to query offers for regions on level1, level2 and level3 regions.

Comment: It's always a good idea to show something you have so far and then ask specific questions about where you currently stand.

Comment: What kind of database are you working with?

Comment: @BertEvans - I know. I just ask because after one day of thinking about this I didn't create any solution. I have only hierarhy of regions. Each region have id and reference to parent region in level 1 and level 2. There are 3 levels. I will update my question asap.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is the obvious way which uses an id to point to a parent like this

```
CREATE TABLE Regions (
    region_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id INT,
    region_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES Regions(region_id)
);
```

But in your situation this could be considered an anti-pattern, since it is not so easy to query through the hierarchy (specially if the number of levels changes)

Another approach could be using something like **Path Enumeration**, where you store the hierarchy path similar to for example unix paths. E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Regions (
    region_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    path VARCHAR(100),
    region_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

This will allow you to store your hierarchy like this

```
---------------------------------------------
| region_id | path       | region_name      |
---------------------------------------------
| 1         | 1/         | subregion_1      |
| 2         | 1/2/       | subregion_11     |
| 3         | 1/2/3/     | region_111       |
| 4         | 1/2/4/     | region_112       |
---------------------------------------------
```

This way, when querying your offers table (where each offer will have a ref. to the region_id), and while browsing lets say offer for the subregion_1 (with id 1) your query can look something like this.

```
select Offers.SOME_COLUMN, ......
from Offers, Regions
where Offers.region_id = Regions.region_id
and   Regions.path like '1/%'
```

There are other patterns to model your hierarchical data, such as **[Nested Sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)** and **Closure Table** ([maybe relevant](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html)) which you might be interested to look into as well. each has different pros and cons in terms of select/insert/delete performance

**EDIT:**

I just noticed you edited your question, also that offers could belong to more than one region. The above might need adjustments to support assigning more than one region, but the basic idea could still be applied.

Comment: But what if offer will be added to database with subregion_1 (id=1). This offer should be visible in all branch '1/%' but in this situation it will be visible only in subregion_1 page?

Comment: if an offer is in subergion_1 should it be shown while you browse for example region_111 and subregion_11 and subregion_1? Also if an offer is in region_111 it should be visible in region_111, subregion_11 and subregion_1? If that is the case then I don't see the need for hierarchy anymore to be hones?!?! Just use a many-to-many relationship to define the visibility of an offer

Comment: Yes exacly. This is for drivers and passengers service. If passenges looking for driver in area_1 then he see all offers from the drivers from this area_1 so that's mean he see offers from smaller areas inside area_1 but he didn't see the offers from area_2 for example because this is diffrent geographic terithory. When driver add offer for area_1 then his offer will be visible in all subtree under area_1. But when he add offer in area_1_1 which is subregion inside area_1 then when passenger visit the area_1 site should see the offer because area_1 contains area_1_1.

Comment: Also see my answer explaining Closure Table on SO: [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462).  To support offers in many regions, you'd just need a many-to-many intersection table referencing offers and regions.

Comment: @BillKarwin Your Closure Table idea with little modification are exacly what I need. Now it's working very fast. The hierarhy in my scenario doesn't change in time because it's a regions in country like province, district, city so I load my Closure Table Index into the Mysql cache and it's very very fast solution :) Thank You

Comment: @Marcin: Yes, Closure Table can be very fast if you define the right covering indexes.  Which indexes are the right ones depends on the queries you need to run against it.